# React native, how to show an image of cloud storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I uploaded images but I can't display those images. I followed the documentation and some examples that I saw, tried but didn't get anything. My code now looks like this

```
const imageRef = storage().ref('images/').child('photo-229634742.jpeg').getDownloadURL();
return(
   ...
   <Text>
      {imageRef}
   </Text>
);
```

and in this way, it shows this error
[image]

Can someone help me? I want to show the images I made on the cloud storage

This is my code to upload:

```
    const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState(null)
    const [imagePath, setImagePath] = useState()
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState()
    const [status, setStatus] = useState()

    function chooseFile() {
    setStatus( '' );
    var options = {
        title: 'Select Image',
        storageOptions: {
            skipBackup: true, // do not backup to iCloud
            path: 'images', // store camera images under Pictures/images for android and 
    Documents/images for iOS
        },
    };
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
        setAvatar(response.uri)
        if (response.didCancel) {
            console.log('User cancelled image picker', storage());
        } else if (response.error) {
            console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
        } else if (response.customButton) {
            console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
        } else {
            let path = getPlatformPath(response).value;
            let fileName = getFileName(response.fileName, path);
            setImagePath( path );
            uploadImageToStorage(path, fileName);
            
        }
    });
};

function getFileName(name, path) {
    if (name != null) { return name; }
    
    if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
        path = "~" + path.substring(path.indexOf("/Documents"));
    }
    return path.split("/").pop();
}

function uploadImageToStorage(path, name) {
    setIsLoading({ isLoading: true });
    let reference = storage().ref("images/" + name);
    let task = reference.putFile(path);
    task.then(() => {
        console.log('Image uploaded to the bucket!');
        setIsLoading(false);
        setStatus('Image uploaded successfully');
    }).catch((e) => {
        status = 'Something went wrong';
        console.log('uploading image error => ', e);
        setIsLoading(false);
        setStatus('Something went wrong');
    });
}

/**
 * Get platform specific value from response
 */
function getPlatformPath({ path, uri }) {
    return Platform.select({
        android: { "value": path },
        ios: { "value": uri }
    })
}

function getPlatformURI(imagePath) {
    let imgSource = imagePath;
    if (isNaN(imagePath)) {
        imgSource = { uri: imagePath };
        if (Platform.OS == 'android') {
            imgSource.uri = "images/" + imgSource.uri;
        }
    }
    return imgSource
}
```

Comment: getDownloadURL returns a promise, not an actual string URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer assumes that your images are actually being uploaded to Cloud Storage.**

You **cannot** render an image from within a `Text tag`, the `imageRef` constant you're declaring is a `method` which returns a `download url`, you want to store that url in `state` to be able to call it from within an `image tag`.

Code would look something like this:

```
const [url, setUrl] = useState();

let imageRef = firebase.storage().ref('images/photo-229634742.jpeg');
imageRef
.getDownloadURL()
.then((url) => {
  setUrl(url);
})
.catch((e) => console.log('getting downloadURL of image error => ', e));
```

and then you can call it from an Image tag as in `<Image source={{uri:url}}/>`

The reason you need to store the url in `state` is because the `getDownloadUrl()` method returns a **promise** rather than a **string** of text. That promise cannot be used directly as a way to render the image. The promise is unaccessible from outside the `imageRef function` by itself. You can check this out by removing the state like this:

```
let imageRef = firebase.storage().ref('images/photo-229634742.jpeg');
imageRef
.getDownloadURL()
.catch((e) => console.log('getting downloadURL of image error => ', e));
console.log(url)
```

You'll see that it returns **undefined**. By storing it in state you expand the scope of it and make it accessible from outside the method. In that way you can call it from anywhere in the file you're working in.

Comment: The cool one, I saw that I was able to show the url, but I couldn't save it in the variable. Is it simply because of the `state`? Could you explain to me why?

Comment: I've added an explanation to my answer, you can check it out, if that still doesn't make things clear, let me know.

Comment: I asked a new question, if you know and can answer, I will be very grateful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65134186/how-do-i-make-an-array-in-state-reactnative

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see this in time. Good to see someone helped already though.