# how do I make an array in state - reactnative

Tags: react-native

I'm taking the images I uploaded to cloud storage, but the problem is the variable is not an array, so it is only storing just one url. How do I make variables with state array?

My code:

```
const reference = storage().ref('images');
const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState();
const refer = storage().ref('images');

useEffect(() => {
    try {
        listFilesAndDirectories(reference).then(() => {
            console.log('Finished listing');
        });
        refer.list().then(result => {
            result.items.forEach(element => {
                element.getDownloadURL().then(downloadUrl => {
                    setImageUrl(downloadUrl)
                    console.log(imageUrl)
                    console.log("=================")
                }).catch(error =>{
                    alert(error)
                })
            })
        })
    } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
    }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

const handleStateChange = () => {
  setItems(state => [...state, 'someNewItem']);
}
```

With useCallback

```
const handleStateChange = useCallback(function () {
    setItems(state => [...state, 'someNewItem']);
}, [])
```

Comment: A good answer provides a clear explanation on why your solution is the most adequate and the fundamental concepts behind it. Rather than providing the easy way out with a simple code snippet, you should try to share your knowledge so the person asking learns how to solve a future issue rather than just solve this particular problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, helped me a lot